# How to read ppt file in php?

Tags: php, powerpoint

I would like to read  korean language , count characters , words from ppt file in php. I have used the below php code to read ppt file but it does not read korean language -

```
function parsePPT($filename) {
     // This approach uses detection of the string "chr(0f).Hex_value.chr(0x00).chr(0x00).chr(0x00)" to find text strings, which are then terminated by another NUL chr(0x00). [1] Get text between delimiters [2] 
    $fileHandle = fopen($filename, "r");
    $line = fread($fileHandle, filesize($filename));
    $lines = explode(chr(0x0f),$line);
    $outtext = '';

    foreach($lines as $thisline) {
        if (strpos($thisline, chr(0x00).chr(0x00).chr(0x00)) == 1) {
            $text_line = substr($thisline, 4);
            $end_pos   = strpos($text_line, chr(0x00));
            $text_line = substr($text_line, 0, $end_pos);
            $text_line = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s\,\.\-\n\r\t@\/\_\(\)]/"," ",$text_line);
            if (strlen($text_line) > 1) {
                $outtext.= substr($text_line, 0, $end_pos)."\n";
            }
        }
    }

    return $outtext;
}

$filename = "test_pptk.ppt";
$ppt_string = parsePPT($filename);
```

Please tell me about php code which can read korean and other languages from ppt file. I also want to count number of characters and number of words in such ppt file.

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions - instead, you should edit your original question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26775665/how-to-read-korean-language-ppt-file-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [PHPPowerPoint](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPPowerPoint) library.

Comment: How can i use phppowerpoint library. i tried to use it bt it asking for to install composer.json , Kindly please tell me the steps to use PHPPowerPoint library. Thanx

Comment: `require_once 'path/to/PhpPowerpoint/src/PhpPowerpoint/Autoloader.php';
\PhpOffice\PhpPowerpoint\Autoloader::register();`